# Maximize the sum of cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

$x_n=\{x:x \in[-1,2]\}$

Find the maximum value of $\ \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{100}x^3_i \ \ \ \ \ $ if $\ \ \ \  \sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i=2$

My attempt:

For the "cube sum" to be maximum the $x_i$ has to take the maximum value i.e. 2 but due to the constraint of the linear sum, we have to subtract some terms to balance it out. Hence $x_i \in \{-1,2\}$.

So, $\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i=2a-b=2$ where $a+b=100$.

On solving the the linear equation, we get $a=34$ and $b=66$

Using this newly found information: $\sum_{i=1}^{100}x^3_i=8a-b=8\cdot34-66=206$ which is the maximum value of the function. But I am not sure how to prove this rigorously.

Please provide hints to solve it rigorously.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a way without using the lagrangian?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Make $x_i = a(\sin u_i +b)$ and forming the lagrangian

$$
L = \sum_i^{100} a^3(\sin u_i +b)^3-\lambda\left(\sum_i^{100}a(\sin u_i +b)-2\right)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\cases{
3a^3(\sin u_i+b)^2\cos u_i-\lambda a\cos u_i = 0,\ \ i=1,\cdots, 100\\
\sum_i^{100}a(\sin u_i +b)-2=0}
$$

then we have

$$
\cos u_i = 0\\
a^2(\sin u_i+b)^2 = \frac{\lambda}{3}
$$

and then $100\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{3}} = 2$ etc.

NOTE

$$
\cases{
a = \frac 32\\
b = \frac 13
}
$$

From $\cos u_i = 0$ we have $u_i = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ and then the maximum is attained when

$$
\cases{
-n+2m=2\\
n+m=100
}
$$

associated to this condition we have $\max \sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i^3 = 66(-1)+34(2^3)$ and now we can follow analyzing  the stationary points associated to $\cases{a^2(\sin u_i+b)^2 = \frac{\lambda}{3}\\ 100\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{3}} = 2}$ etc.

Comment: Could you provide an entire solution? I do not know how to use the lagrangian.

Comment: Added some comments.

Comment: Thank you I understood your answer